# Exclude empty columns while using concat_ws

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with columns of StringType. I need to concatenate 3 columns and place the results in a different column. I am using concat_ws like this:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

def myConcat(*cols):
    return f.trim(f.concat_ws('-', *[f.coalesce(c, f.lit("")) for c in cols]))

df = df.withColumn('Column1', myConcat(df['Column2'], df['Column3'], df['Column4'])).show()
```

This is the desired result:

```
+--------------+-----------+---------+--------+
|Column1       |Column2    |Column3  |Column4 |
+--------------+-----------+---------+--------+
| abcd-efg-hij |   abcd    |      efg|  hij   |
| s675-klm     |   s675    |         |  klm   |
+--------------+-----------+---------+--------+
```

However, some of the columns are empty and when I run the above script, I get something like this:

```
+--------------+-----------+---------+--------+
|Column1       |Column2    |Column3  |Column4 |
+--------------+-----------+---------+--------+
| abcd-efg-hij |   abcd    |      efg|  hij   |
| s675--klm    |   s675    |         |  klm   |
+--------------+-----------+---------+--------+
```

A double -- in the second row result.

Is there a way to avoid this and get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing empty string in the String column as NULL should work:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

def myConcat(*cols):
    return f.trim(f.concat_ws('-', *[f.when(c != '', c) for c in cols]))

df.withColumn('Column1', myConcat(df['Column2'], df['Column3'], df['Column4'])).show()
#+-------+-------+-------+------------+
#|Column2|Column3|Column4|     Column1|
#+-------+-------+-------+------------+
#|   abcd|    efg|    hij|abcd-efg-hij|
#|   s675|       |    klm|    s675-klm|
#+-------+-------+-------+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer. Worked like a charm.